# ¿Por qué al llamar a un modal dentro de otro modal mi app deja de reconocer que hay un modal mostrándose?

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap-3

**Explico un poco más:**

Muestro un `modal`y en el quiero agregar mas `items` al `select`; la opción funciona correctamente, pero cuando el `modal` que registra nuevos items al `select` se oculta el primer `modal` es ignorado, como sino estuviera.

A lo que me refierio con "como sino estuviera" es que hasta el `scroll` desaparece.

**Acá el código de mi formulario:**

```js
  $(document).on('click', '#Crear', function() {
        $('#ModalCrear').modal('show');
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#agregar_nombres', function() {
        $('#ModalAgregarNombre').modal('show');
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


    <button type="button" id="Crear" class="btn btn-primary">
        <span class="fa fa-plus"></span> Agregar
    </button>

    <div id="ModalCrear" class="modal fade" role="dialog"> 
     <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header"> 
        <h4 class="modal-tittle">Crear</h4> 
       </div> 
       <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="form-crear">
        <div class="modal-body"> 
         <div class="row form-group col-md-12">
          <label for="crear_codigo" class="control-label col-sm-2 col-xs-12">Código: </label>
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
           <input type="number" class="form-control" id="crear_codigo" name="crear_codigo">
          </div>
         </div>  
         <div class="row form-group col-md-12">
          <label for="crear_nombre" class="control-label col-sm-2 col-xs-12">Nombre: </label>
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-10 selectContainer">
           <select id="crear_nombre" name="crear_nombre" class="form-control" style="width: 100%;">
                                        <option value="0">Seleccione...</option>
                                        <option value="1">Clorace</option>
                                        <option value="2">Miovit</option>
           </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="agregar_nombres">
            <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
                           <span class="hidden-xs"> Agregar Items</span> 
           </button>
          </div>
         </div> 
         <div class="row form-group col-md-12">
          <label for="crear_formas_farmaceuticas" class="control-label col-sm-2 col-xs-12">Forma Farmacéutica: </label>
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-10 selectContainer">
           <select id="crear_formas_farmaceuticas" class="form-control" name="crear_formas_farmaceuticas" style="width: 100%;">
                                        <option value="0">Seleccione...</option>
                                        <option value="1">Inyección</option>
                                        <option value="2">Jarabe</option>
           </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-2">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="agregar_formas">
            <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
                           <span class="hidden-xs"> Agregar Items</span> 
           </button>
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row form-group col-md-12">
          <label for="crear_presentacion" class="control-label col-sm-2 col-xs-12">Presentación: </label>
          <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-5">
           <input type="number" class="form-control" id="crear_presentacion" name="crear_presentacion">
          </div> 
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-7 selectContainer">
           <select id="crear_unidad_de_medicion_p" class="form-control" name="crear_unidad_de_medicion_p" style="width: 100%;">
                                        <option value="0">Seleccione...</option>
                                        <option value="1">(und) Unidad</option>
                                        <option value="2">(ml) Mililitro</option>
                                        <option value="2">(mg) Miligramo</option>
           </select>
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row form-group col-md-12">
          <label for="crear_unidad_teorica" class="control-label col-sm-2 col-xs-12">Unidad Teórica: </label>
          <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
           <input type="number" class="form-control" id="crear_unidad_teorica" name="crear_unidad_teorica">
          </div> 
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-7 selectContainer">
           <select id="crear_unidad_de_medicion_u" class="form-control" name="crear_unidad_de_medicion_u" style="width: 100%;">
                                        <option value="0">Seleccione...</option>
                                        <option value="1">(und) Unidad</option>
                                        <option value="2">(ml) Mililitro</option>
                                        <option value="2">(mg) Miligramo</option>
           </select>
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row form-group col-md-12">
          <label for="crear_velocidad" class="control-label col-sm-2 col-xs-12">Velocidad del Producto: </label>
          <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-5">
           <input type="number" class="form-control" id="crear_velocidad" name="crear_velocidad">
          </div> 
          <label class="col-sm-5 col-xs-7">
           <h4>
            <sup id="crear_unidad_de_medicion_v_u" name="crear_unidad_de_medicion_v_u">
             
            </sup>
            /
            <sub id="crear_unidad_de_medicion_v_t" name="crear_unidad_de_medicion_v_t">
             min
            </sub>
           </h4>
          </label>
         </div>
         <div class="row form-group col-md-12">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2 col-xs-12">Tiempo Teórico: </label>
          <label class="col-sm-7 col-xs-7">
           <h4>
            <sub id="crear_tiempo_teorico" name="crear_tiempo_teorico">
             
            </sub>
           </h4>
          </label>
         </div>
         <div class="row form-group col-md-12">
          <label for="crear_linea_de_produccion" class="control-label col-sm-2">Linea de Producción:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8 selectContainer">
           <select id="crear_linea_de_produccion" class="form-control" name="crear_linea_de_produccion" style="width: 100%;">
                                        <option value="0">Seleccione...</option>
                                        <option value="1">Liquidos Esteriles</option>
                                        <option value="2">Liquidos No Esteriles</option>
                                        <option value="2">Solidos</option>
           </select>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                         <span class="hidden-xs"> Cerrar</span> 
         </button>
         <button type="button" id="Guardar" name="Guardar" class="btn btn-primary">
          <span class="fa fa-save"></span>
                         <span class="hidden-xs"> Guardar</span> 
         </button>
        </div>
       </form>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div id="ModalAgregarNombre" class="modal fade" role="dialog"> 
     <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header"> 
        <h4 class="modal-tittle">Agregar</h4>
       </div> 
       <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="form-agregar">
        <div class="modal-body"> 
         <div class="form-group col-md-12">
          <label for="agregar_nombre" class="control-label col-sm-4">Nombre: </label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="agregar_nombre" name="agregar_nombre">
          </div>
         </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span><span class="hidden-xs"> Cerrar</span>
         </button>
         <button type="button" id="GuardarNombre" name="GuardarNombre" class="btn btn-primary">
          <span class="fa fa-save"></span><span class="hidden-xs"> Guardar</span>
                          
         </button>
        </div>
       </form>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

**NOTA:**

Si abren el modal `ModalCrear` ese funciona bien, luego abres el modal `modalAgregarNombre` este también funciona bien pero cuando lo mando a ocultar el modal `ModalCrear` deja de funcionar el `scroll` del navegador, si estoy en un dispositivo con poca resolución me de funcionar ese modal porque nunca podrá bajar para darle a los botones de acción o rellenar los otros campos que no se aprecian.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Pareciera ser que al abrir el modal y luego ocultarlo, el mismo Bootstrap quita la barra de navegación. Para corregirlo agrega un estilo `style="overflow-y: scroll;"` al `div` `ModalCrear` para que quede de esta forma:

```
<div id="ModalCrear" class="modal fade" role="dialog" style="overflow-y: scroll;">
```

## Demostración:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#Crear', function() {
        $('#ModalCrear').modal('show');
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#agregar_nombres', function() {
        $('#ModalAgregarNombre').modal('show');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


    <button type="button" id="Crear" class="btn btn-primary">
        <span class="fa fa-plus"></span> Agregar
    </button>

    <div id="ModalCrear" class="modal fade" role="dialog" style="overflow-y: scroll;"> 
     <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header"> 
        <h4 class="modal-tittle">Crear</h4> 
       </div> 
       <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="form-crear">
        <div class="modal-body"> 
         <div class="row form-group col-md-12">
          <label for="crear_codigo" class="control-label col-sm-2 col-xs-12">Código: </label>
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
           <input type="number" class="form-control" id="crear_codigo" name="crear_codigo">
          </div>
         </div>  
         <div class="row form-group col-md-12">
          <label for="crear_nombre" class="control-label col-sm-2 col-xs-12">Nombre: </label>
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-10 selectContainer">
           <select id="crear_nombre" name="crear_nombre" class="form-control" style="width: 100%;">
                                        <option value="0">Seleccione...</option>
                                        <option value="1">Clorace</option>
                                        <option value="2">Miovit</option>
           </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="agregar_nombres">
            <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
                           <span class="hidden-xs"> Agregar Items</span> 
           </button>
          </div>
         </div> 
         <div class="row form-group col-md-12">
          <label for="crear_formas_farmaceuticas" class="control-label col-sm-2 col-xs-12">Forma Farmacéutica: </label>
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-10 selectContainer">
           <select id="crear_formas_farmaceuticas" class="form-control" name="crear_formas_farmaceuticas" style="width: 100%;">
                                        <option value="0">Seleccione...</option>
                                        <option value="1">Inyección</option>
                                        <option value="2">Jarabe</option>
           </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-2">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="agregar_formas">
            <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
                           <span class="hidden-xs"> Agregar Items</span> 
           </button>
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row form-group col-md-12">
          <label for="crear_presentacion" class="control-label col-sm-2 col-xs-12">Presentación: </label>
          <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-5">
           <input type="number" class="form-control" id="crear_presentacion" name="crear_presentacion">
          </div> 
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-7 selectContainer">
           <select id="crear_unidad_de_medicion_p" class="form-control" name="crear_unidad_de_medicion_p" style="width: 100%;">
                                        <option value="0">Seleccione...</option>
                                        <option value="1">(und) Unidad</option>
                                        <option value="2">(ml) Mililitro</option>
                                        <option value="2">(mg) Miligramo</option>
           </select>
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row form-group col-md-12">
          <label for="crear_unidad_teorica" class="control-label col-sm-2 col-xs-12">Unidad Teórica: </label>
          <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
           <input type="number" class="form-control" id="crear_unidad_teorica" name="crear_unidad_teorica">
          </div> 
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-7 selectContainer">
           <select id="crear_unidad_de_medicion_u" class="form-control" name="crear_unidad_de_medicion_u" style="width: 100%;">
                                        <option value="0">Seleccione...</option>
                                        <option value="1">(und) Unidad</option>
                                        <option value="2">(ml) Mililitro</option>
                                        <option value="2">(mg) Miligramo</option>
           </select>
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row form-group col-md-12">
          <label for="crear_velocidad" class="control-label col-sm-2 col-xs-12">Velocidad del Producto: </label>
          <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-5">
           <input type="number" class="form-control" id="crear_velocidad" name="crear_velocidad">
          </div> 
          <label class="col-sm-5 col-xs-7">
           <h4>
            <sup id="crear_unidad_de_medicion_v_u" name="crear_unidad_de_medicion_v_u">
             
            </sup>
            /
            <sub id="crear_unidad_de_medicion_v_t" name="crear_unidad_de_medicion_v_t">
             min
            </sub>
           </h4>
          </label>
         </div>
         <div class="row form-group col-md-12">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2 col-xs-12">Tiempo Teórico: </label>
          <label class="col-sm-7 col-xs-7">
           <h4>
            <sub id="crear_tiempo_teorico" name="crear_tiempo_teorico">
             
            </sub>
           </h4>
          </label>
         </div>
         <div class="row form-group col-md-12">
          <label for="crear_linea_de_produccion" class="control-label col-sm-2">Linea de Producción:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8 selectContainer">
           <select id="crear_linea_de_produccion" class="form-control" name="crear_linea_de_produccion" style="width: 100%;">
                                        <option value="0">Seleccione...</option>
                                        <option value="1">Liquidos Esteriles</option>
                                        <option value="2">Liquidos No Esteriles</option>
                                        <option value="2">Solidos</option>
           </select>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                         <span class="hidden-xs"> Cerrar</span> 
         </button>
         <button type="button" id="Guardar" name="Guardar" class="btn btn-primary">
          <span class="fa fa-save"></span>
                         <span class="hidden-xs"> Guardar</span> 
         </button>
        </div>
       </form>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div id="ModalAgregarNombre" class="modal fade" role="dialog"> 
     <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header"> 
        <h4 class="modal-tittle">Agregar</h4>
       </div> 
       <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="form-agregar">
        <div class="modal-body"> 
         <div class="form-group col-md-12">
          <label for="agregar_nombre" class="control-label col-sm-4">Nombre: </label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="agregar_nombre" name="agregar_nombre">
          </div>
         </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span><span class="hidden-xs"> Cerrar</span>
         </button>
         <button type="button" id="GuardarNombre" name="GuardarNombre" class="btn btn-primary">
          <span class="fa fa-save"></span><span class="hidden-xs"> Guardar</span>
                          
         </button>
        </div>
       </form>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Tenía el mismo problema, gracias solucionado!!!